# How to show Google trademark logo on Google Maps when using PhoneGap on iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, cordova, appstore-approval

I developed an iPhone application using PhoneGap everything works fine, I sent the app for review to publish on the App store.

I received a rejection report stating the issue:

> 8.6 : Google Maps and Google earth Images obtained via the Google Maps Api can be used within an application if all brand features of the
>   original content remain unaltered and fully visible. App that cover up
>   or modify the Google logo or copyright holders identification will be
>   rejected.

I use Google Maps API v3, on a PHP page that I load with Ajax into my application. I don't hide anything but the logo does not appear in the application, it only appears on the web browser or on Safari on my iPhone. 
The link is http://mourady.me/alhokair/iphone/maps.php.

Comment: It sounds like you have a case to have your app re-evaluated. Also, it sounds like Apple is beging a jerk.

Comment: I disagree with Simon: just because you don't actively hide it yourself doesn't mean the app should be allowed. It could well be a result of the way the map is loaded into the app, and if so that needs to be sorted. The link shows the map works; but we have no data about how the app does its stuff. Can you provide a mock-up of that (loading a map by AJAX like the app, but in a browser) and demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Is the WebView in Phonegap cropping the Google Map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is How I solved my problem , i found out it something concerning the height of the map canvas with height of the div the the canvas is loaded into as i was using phonegap.

so i loaded google maps in my webbrowser normally and copied the logo div and changed its position to apear in the mobile map and apple accepted that easily

```
<div style="margin: 2px 5px 2px 2px; z-index: 1000000; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 66px; "><a style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline; " title="Click to see this area on Google Maps" target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=42.228517,164.003906&amp;z=2&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US"><div style="width: 62px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer; "><img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 62px; height: 24px; " src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/google_white.png"></div></a></div>
```